# Session works properly in Localhost but not in CPANEL

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a Login system which i have used session while loging to the account. in

localhost each and everything is working properly, but in MY CPANEL its showing the following

problems:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php:1) in /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php on line 3


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php:1) in /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php on line 20


<?php

session_start();
require_once('../../Admin Panel/db.php');
if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $query="SELECT RemoteEmployeeFullName, RemoteEmployeeEmail, RemoteEmployeePassword FROM remoteemployees WHERE RemoteEmployeeEmail='".$email."' AND RemoteEmployeePassword='".$password."'";
 $queryrun=$connection->query($query);
 if($queryrun->num_rows > 0)
 {

     $_SESSION['email']=$RemoteEmployeeFullName;     
     header('Location:REPLists.php');
 }
 else
 {
     echo 'Email: <b>'.$email. '</b> or Password <b>'. $password.'</b> Is Not Typed Correctly Try Again Please!.';
     header( "refresh:5;url=../../spd/myaccount.php" );
 }

}
else
{
    header( "refresh:1;url=../../spd/myaccount.php" );
}

?>
```

Comment: is this your `main.php` file?

Comment: ya this is my main.php file

Answer (score 1):

remove extra sapces from start opening and end php tags like:-

```
<?php session_start();
```

also try to check session is already started or not before start new session. or header is already sent [header_sent()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)
also avoid header modification warning messages by buffering your source
ob_start()

Answer (score 0):

Check you don't have ANY whitespace/line breaks before the first