# Session is working in Localhost Properly but not Online (Cpanel)

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys Sorry for my stupid question regarding to my yesterday question its not solved

yet even the advice you have given but still not working. i have removed all of spaces but

still showing the problem for me. it's working perfect in localhost but not in CPANEL.

Here is the errors which give:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php:1) in /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php on line 1

    Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php:1) in /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php on line 1

    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php:1) in /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/main.php on line 13

    Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly relies on a session side-effect which existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be advised that the session extension does not consider global variables as a source of data, unless register_globals is enabled. You can disable this functionality and this warning by setting session.bug_compat_42 or session.bug_compat_warn to off, respectively in Unknown on line 0

ANY ONE PLEASE ???

Here is my code:

    <?php session_start(); 
    require_once('../../Admin Panel/db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
    {
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $query="SELECT RemoteEmployeeFullName, RemoteEmployeeEmail, RemoteEmployeePassword FROM remoteemployees WHERE RemoteEmployeeEmail='".$email."' AND RemoteEmployeePassword='".$password."'";
     $queryrun=$connection->query($query);
     if($queryrun->num_rows > 0)
     {
         $_SESSION['email']=$RemoteEmployeeFullName;     
         header("Location: /home/scalepro/public_html/Admin Panel/Remote Employee/REPLists.php");
     }
     else
     {
        echo 'Email: <b>'.$email. '</b> or Password <b>'. $password.'</b> Is Not Typed Correctly Try Again Please!.';
        header( "refresh:5;url= /home/scalepro/public_html/spd/myaccount.php" );
     }

    }
    else
    {
        header( "refresh:5;url= /home/scalepro/public_html/spd/myaccount.php" );
    }
    ?>
```

if the condition gets true this will be redirected to a page by the name of REPLists.php

here is the page.

```
<?php session_start();
require_once('../../Admin Panel/db.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrapper
{
  width:1250px;
  height:auto;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -ms-border-radius:5px;
}
.wrapper .header
{
  width:1250px;
  height:20px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #f0eeee;
  margin:auto 0;
  margin-bottom:12px;
}
.wrapper .header div
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#F60;
}
.wrapper .header div a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#F60;
}
.wrapper .Labelcon
{
  width:1250px;
  height:29px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;
}

.wrapper .Labelcon .Label
{
  width:125px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:14.3px;
  font-weight:bold;

}
.wrapper .Valuecon
{
  width:1250px;
  height:29px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;
  color:#F60;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.wrapper .Valuecon .Value
{
  width:125px;
  height:20px;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #f0eeee;
  font-size:14px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header">
<div style="float:left;"><font color="#000000">Email: 
</font>
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
echo $_SESSION['email'];
}
?>

</div>
<div style="float:right;">  <a href="#">My Profile</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
</div>


<div class="Labelcon">
  <div class="Label">Property ID</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Type</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Deal Type</div>
  <div class="Label">Property Owner</div>
  <div class="Label">Proposted Price</div>
</div>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
  header('Location:../../spd/myaccount.php');
}
else
{
  $query = "SELECT 
   properties.PropertyID,
   properties.PropertyType,
   properties.PropertyDealType,
   properties.Status,
   properties.PropostedPrice,

   remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeFullName,

   propertyowners.PropertyOwnerName,
   propertydealers.PropertyDealerName

   FROM remoteemployees,
        propertyowners,
        propertydealers,
        properties

   WHERE 

   properties.PropertyOwnerID=propertyowners.PropertyOwnerID

   AND properties.PropertyDealerID=propertydealers.PropertyDealerID

   AND remoteemployees.RemoteEmployeeID=properties.RemoteEmployeeID



   ORDER BY properties.PropertyID
   ";

  $query_run = $connection->query($query);
  if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
  while($row=$query_run->fetch_assoc()) 
  {

?>
<div class="Valuecon">
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyID'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyType'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyDealType']?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropertyOwnerName'] ?></div>
  <div class="Value"><?php echo $row['PropostedPrice'];?></div>
</div>

<?php } }?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some characters before `<?php` in your code somewhere... maybe in an included file.  Strip your code down until the error goes away.  It's working on your localhost only because you have output buffering on.  The problem is your code, not your host.

Comment: put `exit();` after `header`.

Comment: what does that do @YogeshSuthar

Comment: there is only one space after <?php tag then the session_start(); if i remove this space also it will not be any more a php code

Comment: @DevZer0 It will solve the `Cannot modify header information` warning message.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289134/session-works-properly-in-localhost-but-not-in-cpanel/17289293#17289293

Answer (score 1):

You need to put  `ob_start()` at the beginning of your script and `ob_flush()` at the end. its doing this because your headers are already sent and `session_start` will throw an error because its attempting to send another header parameter.

```
<?php 
  // ob_start holds data in the script, 
  // instead of sending data in pieces
  ob_start();

  // your php code

  // ob_flush sends all the data to the browser
  ob_flush();
?>
```

**Edit:** also any whitespace, html code before `<?php` or after `?>` the php tags can cause this error.  there is a great answer on this question here at SO **[Headers already sent by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)**

Comment: As you have given instruction i did like that but still problem exist.

Comment: did you put it in the first file that is included ? and when it redirects to a new one, you'll need to add it there too.

Comment: i cant paste the whole code in here any way to paste all 3 pages code plz

Comment: you have three similar errors `headers already sent` and the fourth i never seen before. the three are referring to header calls in your if else statements `header( "refresh:5;url= /home/scalepro/public_html/spd/myaccount.php" );` putting all header  and session calls in between `ob_start();` and `ob_flush();` should solve your problem.

Comment: you mean there is a prob with my if else statement, also i have used exit(); after each header

Comment: no its not the if else i was just telling you, that you can't modify the header without buffering your script. is there any whitespace before your <?php tag and is your <?php before all html elements?

Comment: any space for posting my codes cause there is no extra spaces in header and start of my php tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no whitespace or text outputted before `session_start()`.

Comment: there is no extra spaces before the session_start();

Comment: It could also be before `<?php`

Comment: also no space before the <?php

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove any code before `<?php session_start()` which you've already removed. At least that's what you think. I had my header included in my index.php after some code. I removed session_start from header and put this as the very first code in my index.php or any other main.php file.

```
<?php ob_start();if(!isset(session)){session_start();}
else echo "Session Started already, bro!?>
```